# How can I look for data in nested property in a firestore collection?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have been using Firestore as a database for my project.

I have been building an app that stores paths  which are generated by reading gpx files. The collection I use to store them is built like this:

[image]

Each document is a different trail path.

What I would like to do is conditionally search through the collection "paths". I have been reading this documentation : https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries?hl=en

The condition will be to return result which are with X kms using latitude and longitude values, which are stored in the nested array "coordonnees".

I would like to know if there is a way to use this kind of expression below to look for data where coordonnees.lat < X and coordonnees.lng < X for example ???

```js
citiesRef.where("state", ">=", "CA").where("state", "<=", "IN");
```

The goal is that people will type their location, and I want to return them the stored files that are near the location they typed in. If you know a better or another way to reach the same goal, it would nice too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find documents that are around a certain location. While Firestore has a GeoPoint data type built-in, it unfortunately not currently support performing geoqueries on those.

The best option is to use an add-on library based on geohashes, as explained in the documentation on [performing geoqueries on Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries).

Comment: I had the time today to look into it. It works perfectly, i did not know about this. Thank you very much